# Java sign of number code

Tags: java

I am trying to return the sign of a number using my code here but there seems to be a problem with my use of return? Help por favor?

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReturnTest {
    public static int sign(int n) {
        if (n > 0)
            return 1;
        else if (n == 0)
            return 0;
            else if (n < 0)
                return -1;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Sign of a number"?

Comment: you might want to use Integer.signum(int i)

Comment: One more thing, default language here is English, not Spanish. Por favor, escribe tus preguntas totalmente en inglés para que no hayan problemas a futuro :).

Comment: Dude everyone understands por favor. Don't be a nyit. And anyway that was a dumb mistake of mine. I am new to java.

Comment: I'm a native Spanish speaker and I can say not everybody understands *por favor*, and that was an advice. By the way, I'm one of the people that answered your question :).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not returning a method from all the paths in your method. You can see this by indenting the code accordingly based on [Oracle Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html):

```
public static int sign(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
        } else if (n < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    //needs a return here...
}
```

This can be fixed by having a default return value at the bottom. The code may look like:

```
public static int sign(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

There are other ways to implement this, but I prefer to do a fix based on your current implementation.

---

From your comments, looks like you're in your first steps to learn Java. To make an application, you need an entry point. This is marked by the `main` method which has this signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

So, in your current class, you can add this method and use it to call your `sign` method. I'll show a very basic sample:

```
public class ReturnTest {
    public static int sign(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        int signOfN = sign(n);
        System.out.println("The sign of " + n + " is: " + signOfN);
    }
}
```

It depends to you to adapt this code for your needs. I highly recommend you learn the basics. You can start here:

- [Trail: Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html), Oracle tutorial about Java basic concepts.
- [Lesson: A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html), just to have a better understanding about the most basic application, the "Hello World!".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This may be a dumb question, but I am getting "no main methods, applets, or MIDlets found in file" when I run it. It compiles, but how do I implement the 'main' method in my code?

Comment: @user2861029 create a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. This method will be the entry point for your application.

Comment: you're the best. Sorry for my comment earlier :)

Comment: @Luigi Mendoza wait, how do I implement the public static void main(String[] args) into my code with public static int sign(int n) in it? I keep getting a compilation error of illegal start of expression. I get that the method is sort of a signature for java, but how do I use it in my code?

Comment: Oh wow. I had been going about it all wrong. This makes life much better.

Answer (score 3):

```
   public static int sign(int n) 
   {
       if (n > 0)
          return 1;
       else if (n < 0)
          return -1;

       return 0;
   }
```

The last `if-else` was unnecessary. I've re-ordered to the 'usual' way of falling through at zero. Writing the code like this is  shorter, cleaner and easier to understand

Comment: Hey I am getting this message, my code compiles now but when I run it I get "no main methoads, applets, or MIDlets found in file" What does that mean?

Comment: It means you don't have a main method.

Comment: where do I write the main?

Answer (score 1):

Spare the last if (`if (n < 0)`) because otherwise there is a theoretical branch where the function is never left!
Each branch must return!